# Indesign: PDF hyperlink to a specific line

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, interactive

I am unable to find the way to export a PDF from InDesign where hyperlinks go directly to a specific line (not just a page), but at any zoom level. All the PDFs I've exported zoomed to fit page when you click the hyperlink.

Ideally not using third party software.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

- select a word on that specific line you are pointing to and go to 'Hyperlinks → New hyperlink destination', choose 'Text Anchor', give it a name (ABC) and hit 'Ok'. This is the target (or destination) of the link you are building.
- then, select the word where you need to be able to click and go to 'Hyperlinks → New hyperlink', link to to 'Text anchor' and select what you created in the previous step (ABC). This is the source of the link you are building.
- export to PDF with 'Hyperlinks' checked

Further info: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/hyperlinks.html

Comment: I have been doing that in many ways, but when I reach the linked page, it always zoom to fit to page

Comment: You must be doing something wrong or maybe there's some default behaviour hardcoded when exporting (check which export preset is being used) or with the reader you are using. Click the first word of this pdf at any zoom level and it takes you to the bottom without changing the zoom level. https://we.tl/q8TN0A9pFA

Comment: Yes, it works, but for some reason it doesn't in my InDesign. I tried in other computer and works fine. Now I'm sure that is the correct way to make it. Thank you.

Comment: I finally checked it in my computer, and it works, the problem was me, hehehe. In addition, is there a way to create a TOC liked to that anchored texts, but not to do it line by line? I mean, I don't want to  anchor avery text and then hyperlink every destination. It would take a huge amount of time.

Comment: I find this works but if you are viewing at full page it won't change the zoom level and therefore essentially just link to the page that your anchor is on. If you're zoomed in already on the page you're linking from then it links directly to the specific part of the page where you set your anchor. Is this the best Indesign can do or can you change the Zoom level as well?